# Is there a list of prototype methods you can not override?

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype

I'm looking for a list of prototype methods in JavaScript that I **can not** override.

In case such a list does not exist - I will be glad to read about any method (or a property - like `location`) that you know that can't be override.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a list yet, but I have found more properties and objects that can't be overridden - `top`, `length` and `location`.

I Will try to check all the overrides that are not working in window later today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there a *list* anywhere, as such, but in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) such properties are tagged with `[LegacyUnforgeable]`, so you can just search for that string in the spec and you should find them.  There aren't many, actually.